# Windows 10 won't boot after removing data-only hard drive

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, boot, multi-boot

I'm running Windows 10 on **"C"**. All my data has been stored on **"E"**. I duplicated my files to a new, larger data drive **"Z"**, and removed "E", the old data drive. Suddenly Windows 10 wouldn't boot:
*"The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible."*

Once I reconnected "E", Windows 10 booted.

Windows 7 was previously installed on "E", though I haven't booted to it in years. Disk Management tells me that "E" still has a 100MB "System Reserved" partition marked "System, Active, Primary Partition". I read that even though Windows 10 is on another drive ("C"), Windows may have stored boot data on "E"'s "System Reserved" partition.

There was a "Windows Boot Loader" for Windows 7 on "E". I deleted it, but that didn't solve things.

How can I get Windows 10 to boot with "E" removed?

Comment: can you share the error code after "The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible"

Comment: Yes, it's "0xc000000f"